# How do I populate a formula text field for an HTML link that would include multiple fields from the same object?

Tags: formula-field, html

I have dynamic "add to google calendar" links configured for Visualforce templates, but would like to be able to populate the links on our SF event object as a field so users without Visualforce can easily add the field to an HTML template.

Here's what I use in our Visualforce template:

```
<p><apex:outputLink value="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?text={!URLENCODE(RelatedTo.Name)}&amp;details={!URLENCODE(RelatedTo.TargetX_Eventsb__Description__c)}&amp;location={!URLENCODE(RelatedTo.TargetX_Eventsb__Location__c)}&amp;dates={!RelatedTo.Event_Start_Time_Formatted_For_Calendar__c}/{!RelatedTo.Event_Event_Time_Formatted_For_Calendar__c}" id="GoogleCalendar">Add to Google Calendar</apex:outputLink></p>
```

Is it possible to include multiple fields in a text formula for HTML? I've been playing around with it, without success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use URLFOR for this purpose.

```
<p><apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR('https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit',null,[text=RelatedTo.Name,details=RelatedTo.TargetX_Eventsb__Description__c,location=RelatedTo.TargetX_Eventsb__Location__c,dates=RelatedTo.Event_Start_Time_Formatted_For_Calendar__c&'/'&RelatedTo.Event_Event_Time_Formatted_For_Calendar__c]})" id="GoogleCalendar">Add to Google Calendar</apex:outputLink></p>
```

This automatically handles URL escaping for the parameters.

Comment: Thanks! We're trying to eliminate the need to use a visualforce template and turn it into a field on the organization event object so that it's populated on the object and can be easily inserted by users into an HTML template as a field. It works as is with the visualforce template, and I know starting a formula text field for a link should start with HYPERLINK("